# The entropy of sorted random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, entropy, order-statistics

If the level of each of $n$ process is represented by $iid$ random variables $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$, which has probability distribution as follows $$ p(x_i) =\frac{x_i}{\sigma^2} exp[ -  \frac {x_i^2} {2\sigma^2}]  $$ with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$, let $S$ be a vector of the sorted levels in specific order. How  can I find the entropy of $S$.

Comment: There is some symmetry lying here. Perhaps you can take advantage of that.

Comment: write out the integral form of differential entropy...and observe it is invariant to...

Comment: @Memming when I tried with that I got stuck with $$ H(x) =\int_{-\infty} ^\infty \frac{x} {\sigma^2} \mathrm{e}^{\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}} \mathrm{log} \frac{x} {\sigma^2} \mathrm{d}x - \frac{1} {2} \mathrm{log} \ \mathrm{e} $$ which can be found in some way. But this only for a random variable so how the differential entropy for the whole system above is found, I am a bit confused if some can explain.

Comment: try writing out the joint distribution and see if it factorizes

Comment: Thanks @Memming, so the answer is to find the differential entropy of the multivariate of the distribution above?